# Clickable control inside draggable control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a draggable control (A), within it is a button.  There are also other controls within A, i.e. the button does not fill A.

In order to manage the drag functionality, the control (A) captures any `MouseDown` events.  It later decides whether to start a drag based on how far the mouse has moved.

If the button was clicked, and then a `MouseUp` event is received before a drag has been started, I'd like the button's `Click` event to fire.

At the moment, this doesn't happen because the `MouseUp` event is captured by the parent control (A).  I could implement functionality on A to manually handle this:

```
private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (DragHasStarted) {
        DealWithDrag();
    }
    else {
        DelegateToChildControls();
    }
}
```

However that's complicated and doesn't scale well since `DelegateToChildControls` needs to work out which child to delegate to.

Is there a way to let Windows deal with this and call the button's Click method directly if the parent control doesn't handle the `MouseUp` event?

**Edit - More detail on event sequence:**

I see the following sequence of events when the button is clicked:

1. `MouseDown` on Button
2. `MouseDown` on Button (Drag handler)
3. I forward this to parent of button
4. `MouseDown` on parent (Drag handler)
5. Mouse Captured by parent (Drag handler)
6. `MouseUp` on parent
7. End drag (drag handler)

I never see a `MouseUp` event on the button.

Comment: Do you have an event handler attached to `myButton.Click` already?  Does that not fire when the button is clicked?  Or are you saying that you could "grab" the button and still drag the parent?

Comment: There is an event handler defined.  It does not fire when the button is clicked, because the mouse events are captured by its parent.

Comment: Is that because when you consume `MouseUp` (for instance), you are not forwarding the call with `base.MouseUp(e)` (or the like...)?

Comment: @DonBoitnott I don't forward any calls.  That sounds like what I want to do, but I'm not sure how/if it can be done.  I've edited the question to add the event sequence, hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @Stefan you should have included your comment in your question, if your button is unable to be clicked from outside, you can trigger the click by using `PerformClick()`

Comment: @KingKing The whole point of the question is how to enable the button to be clicked!  I think I made it clear that I want Windows to call Click, not call it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what kind of `Control` as a container you are using, because I've tested with a `UserControl` and I can interact with all the children of my `UserControl`, however if you are interested in clicking on the children only, I have this solution:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT point);
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
struct POINT
{
  public int x, y;
}
private void MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
   if(DragHasStarted){
      DealWithDrag();
   }
   else {
      Point screenLocation = PointToScreen(e.Location);
      IntPtr childHandle = WindowFromPoint(new POINT{x=screenLocation.X,y=screenLocation.Y });
      if(childHandle != IntPtr.Zero){
         SendMessage(childHandle, 0x201, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
         SendMessage(childHandle, 0x202, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not very feasible if the button isn't the only thing in the clickable control.

Comment: @DanPuzey the OP seems to has only that button in his draggable control.

Comment: The post says "There are also other controls within A, i.e. the button does not fill A."

Comment: @DanPuzey I didn't read well enough, I'll update my answer with another solution.